# Doubt on solvability of AX=B

Tags: linear-algebra

I am preparing for an exam, and I had a small doubt so I wanted to ask here.

Suppose A is an $m \times n$ matrix where I have M equations in N unknowns.

Consider a case where $m \lt n$

Now I will have some free variables as my rank cannot exceed m.

Doubt 1: So, for System $AX=B$ I "may" have 0 or infinite solutions and 0 solution is when B does not lie in the column space of the matrix A and infinite solution when B lies in the column space of the matrix A.

Doubt 2 :And for the System $AX=O$ I would always have solution in such case.

Is my claim correct in both doubt 1 and doubt 2?

Answer (score 1):

(In the following Im assuming that the vector spaces that represent the domain and codomain of $A$, as a linear function, are real vector spaces or, in general, are defined over a field of characteristic zero).

Yes, both statements are correct. We have that a matrix $m\times n$, namely $A$, represent a map of the kind

$$A:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m,\quad v\mapsto Av$$

If $m<n$ then $\dim[\ker(A)]\ge 1$, and if $v\in\Bbb R^n$ is a solution for the equation $Av=w$, then $v+z$ is also a solution for any chosen $z\in\ker(A)$.

Hence the solutions are zero (when $w$ dont belong to the image of $A$) or infinite. If $w=0$ then $w$ belongs to the image of $A$ because $A$ represent a linear map (in particular $v=0$ is ever a solution for the equation $Av=0$).